# DatePicker store just Date

Tags: asp.net, telerik, datepicker, raddatepicker

I have a Telerik RadDatePicker in asp.net

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" Width="100px" 
                       DateInput-DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" 
                       DbSelectedDate='<%# Bind("FirstPosDate")%>' 
                       ID="txtFirstPosDate">
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

When I do something like:

```
RadDatePicker firstPosDate = ((RadDatePicker)item.FindControl("txtFirstPosDate"));
var fPosDate = firstPosDate.SelectedDate;
```

I get Date and Time. Is there a way for the SelectedDate to return only the Date?

Comment: Try my answer. RadDatePicker.SelectedDate is a DateTime, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just format the full `DateTime` object to the short date string via the date/time string formatters, like this:

```
var fPostDate = firstPosDate.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
```

Comment: Thanks Karl. I am using the RadDatePicker. Sorry did not mention that. I did try the .Date as you suggested but it would not take it. There is no extension of .Date

Comment: Interesting, because per the Telerik documentation for [SelectedDate](http://www.telerik.com/help/sitefinity/developer-manual/radcalendar.net2-telerik.webcontrols.raddatepicker-selecteddate.html) it is a nullable .NET `DateTime` object. Does `var fPosDate = firstPosDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date;` work?

Comment: Karl, var fPosDate = firstPosDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date still shows Date and Time. Not just the Date like we like it.

Comment: @NatePet - see updated answer to get just the date portion of a `DateTime` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this - http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

`DatePicker.SelectedDate` returns a `DateTime` object, so you can format the object as follows (or one of the many other ways detailed in the link above):

```
var fPosDate = firstPosDate.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // Return 11/20/2013
```